# Redis conflict with postgres - error 'database configuration does not specify adapter'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, redis, capistrano, rails-postgresql

## Problem:

I added Redis to my Rails app, using postgresql (pg gem, redis gem), and now can't deploy to my staging environment.  Cap fails with this error message, after db:schema:dump: `database configuration does not specify an adapter`

The environment passes all specs and runs locally just fine.

If I remove the redis gem, redis.yml and redis.rb, the app deploys fine with no errors.

### Troubleshooting:

Here are the troubleshooting steps I took:

- Confirmed my staging.yml is devoid of hidden characters (proved so by using the same file from a previous commit)
- Backed up to commit before adding redis, and deployed perfectly
- Removed Redmon, on suspicion it was causing the problem
- Upgraded pg to 0.15.1 and redis to 3.0.4 (same error)
- Confirmed that redis-server is, indeed, running on the staging environment

I've hunted far and wide for any mention of this, anywhere, but have only come up with 'your database.yml file has hidden characters'.

I'm going on 9 hours with this problem, so any help would be treMENdously appreciated.

This is my first StackOverflow question, so if I'm missing anything important, please let me know.

### Background:

Here's the actual error I get when I run `cap staging deploy`:

```
* executing "cd /var/www/apps/MY_APP_NAME/current && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake db:migrate"
servers: ["XXX.XXX.XXXX"]
[XXX.XXX.XXXX] executing command
[XXX.XXX.XXXX] /bin/bash -c 'cd /var/www/apps/MY_APP_NAME/current && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake db:migrate'
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] Cannot load Rspec tasks.
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] rake aborted!
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] database configuration does not specify adapter
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] 
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] 
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
** [out :: XXX.XXX.XXXX] 
command finished in 18753ms
```

### Files:

Here's my redis.yml, stored under config\:

```
default:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
development:
  db: 0
test:
  db: 1
staging:
  db: 2
production:
  db: 3
```

Here's my redis.rb, which declares the redis instance, for use in the app:

```
REDIS_CONFIG = YAML.load( File.open( Rails.root.join("config/redis.yml") ) ).symbolize_keys
dflt = REDIS_CONFIG[:default].symbolize_keys
cnfg = dflt.merge(REDIS_CONFIG[Rails.env.to_sym].symbolize_keys) if REDIS_CONFIG[Rails.env.to_sym]

$redis = Redis.new(cnfg)

# To clear out the db before each test
$redis.flushdb if Rails.env = "test"
```

Here's my staging.yml:

```
staging: &staging
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: MY_APP_NAME_staging
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  min_messages: warning
```

Here are the relevant bits of my Gemfile:

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

```
gem 'pg', '0.13.2'
gem 'redis', '3.0.4'
gem 'activeadmin', '0.4.4'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.2.2'
gem 'backup', '3.0.20', :require => false
gem 'backup-task', '0.2.0'
gem 'chargify_api_ares', '0.5.2'
gem 'devise', '2.0'
gem 'dynamic_form', '1.0.0'
gem 'escape_utils', '0.1.9'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
gem 'fog','0.11.0', :require => false
gem 'foreigner', '0.9.1'
gem 'formtastic', '2.1.1'
gem 'haml', '3.1.4'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '2.4.0'
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '1.0.14'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '2.0.10'
gem 'log_buddy', '0.6.0'
gem 'meta_search', '1.1.3'
gem 'mustache', '0.99.4'
gem 'nested_form', :git => "https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git", :ref => "486e0f0e93f3ca455d5d"
gem 'nokogiri', "~> 1.5.0"
gem 'paperclip', '3.1.2'
gem 'rake', "0.9.2", :require => false
gem 'rdiscount', '1.6.5'
gem 'tinymce-rails', '3.5.4.1'
gem 'whenever', '0.6.8', :require => false
gem 'amoeba', '1.2.1'
```

Comment: Figured out that my $redis.flushdb command was the cause of the problem.  After removing that, entirely, I can deploy now.  I had that for clearing the redis store during rspec, so now I need to get that added back in, somehow. Oh well.

Comment: If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Figured out that my $redis.flushdb command was the cause of the
>   problem. After removing that, entirely, I can deploy now. I had that
>   for clearing the redis store during rspec, so now I need to get that
>   added back in, somehow. Oh well.

~ answer per [user1775141](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775141/user1775141)